# gigya change email address when user name

Tags: email, registration, gigya

- We've implemented gigya & have enabled the RaaS policy to use email
  only as the login identifier and enabled email verification.

  - I understand when you register you receive an email to the
    email address with a link to click on to confirm registration & if the user changes a password again they get an email.
  - However I'd like to understand how to handle the situation
    where a user chooses to change their email address (which is their
    user name).
  - My thoughts would be for security an email would be sent
    to the old email address to confirm the change but this does not
    happen.
  - Apparently what happens is the new email added immediately &
    I have to detect something has changed in the account (via an Event,
    even though this is not specific to email address) & make an API
    call to delete the old email address.
  - Is this the recommended approach others have used?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you to understand how that works and how you can handle it:

The `accounts.setAccountInfo` API call (supported by both the Web SDK and the REST API) can be used to add or remove the email addresses that are being used as login identifiers on the account:

- by passing the "removeLoginEmails" parameter as a comma-separated
  list of email addresses that are to be removed
- by passing the "addLoginEmails" parameter as a comma-separated
  list of email addresses that are to be added

**Note:** There must be at least one login identifier left on the account, otherwise this operation will trigger an error. Therefore, if there is only one remaining email address left as a login identifier on the account, it is necessary to make two separate requests (to add first, then remove).

After you manage user emails, you can resend confirmation email with the API call:

```
accounts.resendVerificationCode(params)
```

**Links**

```
http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Account+REST
http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setAccountInfo+REST
http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setAccountInfo+JS
https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.resendVerificationCode+JS
```